# Python markdown not respecting indentation

Tags: python, django, markdown, indentation, pygments

I'm having a problem here: i'm building out a simple blog, and I'm using markdown, pygments and django to do so.

My content is in markdown and I wish to code-highlight it. It works fine, except markdown, is not respecting the indentation of python code.

Here's a screenshot

[image: borked indent]

And here's a screenshot of the content in django admin:

[image: borked indent 2]

Also, the code for rendering in the template:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12 vertical-spacer">
                    {{ object.body|markdown:"safe,codehilite"|render_inlines|safe }}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem ages ago when trying to use the Mingus blog app, which uses Markdown and pygments. The issue appears to stem from the use of the `render_inlines` filter, although I'm not entirely sure why. I wasn't using that particular functionality, so I removed it from the template.

Comment: I'll surely try that, since I wont use inlines either.

Comment: worked like a charm. just waiting for the time period to mark as answered.